# What information is shown in the "canonical-livepatch status --verbose" output?

Tags: command-line, security, canonical-livepatch

When you type `sudo canonical-livepatch status --verbose` into the terminal, are either the `machine id` or `machine token` outputs supposed to display the token given to you by Canonical? Neither of those outputs are the same as the token I received.

What does the `client-version` value indicate? Mine reads `5`.

Also, what are `last-check`, `boot-time`, and `uptime`?

Furthermore, on my display under `status` it says `running: true`, but under `livepatch` it says `state: check-failed`. What do these statements indicate, and how are they related to the `fully-patched` output for the command: `sudo canonical-livepatch status`? For the record, my output reads, `fully-patched: false`.

Why is the `Version` value important, and what does it mean? Mine says `13.3`, yet I have no idea why.

Lastly, what is supposed to be in the `fixes` slot? Mine is blank.

Thanks in advance for your help :) I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS by the way, with the 4.4.0-38.57-generic kernel and 2.16ubuntu3 snapd

Comment: Can you run `man canonical-livepatch`? I don't have it installed so I can't try it.

Comment: You might find some useful info on this blog post: [Hotfix Your Ubuntu Kernels with the Canonical Livepatch Service!](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/10/canonical-livepatch.html)

Comment: Try looking here too: [How to live patch Ubuntu Linux Kernel without rebooting the server](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-live-patch-ubuntu-linux-server-kernel-without-rebooting/)

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting the `state: check-failed` error, and I couldn't find a point-and-click method of getting it to re-check.  The little shield icon in my taskbar had a scary red mark on it, so I knew I had to find a way to fix it.  (Different problem from the OP, but still valid I think).

As to your other questions:  I am not sure about the tokens, but I'm also not sure it's an issue unless you aren't able to get the live update.  Client version is the Live-Update software version; Last-check is the last time the Live-Update software pinged the server to see if there was a security update for you; Boot Time is the last time your machine was booted up and that leads to uptime which is how long your machine has been running since that last boot.  Running means the live-patch software is running in the background; last-check failed, though ... that could mean anything from a network error to a password error.  So I think here is where I'll tell you what I did ...

From the command line, issuing `man canonical-livepatch` results in:

> No manual entry for canonical-livepatch

However, just issuing `canonical-livepatch` results in something more helpful:

> NAME:
>     canonical-livepatch - canonical livepatch client
>
> USAGE:
>     canonical-livepatch [global options] command [command options] [arguments...]
>
> VERSION:
>     9.3.0
>
> AUTHOR:
>     Canonical Livepatch Team
>
> COMMANDS:
>       status   show kernel's livepatch status
>       enable   enable livepatching on the machine
>       disable  disable livepatching on the machine
>       refresh  immediately download and apply any available livepatch
>       config   configure livepatching on the machine
>       help     display help
>
> GLOBAL OPTIONS:
>     --version, -v  print the version

So I just did `sudo canonical-livepatch refresh` which then successfully updated and solved the error.  And my shield icon now has a green check!  Oh happy day!

I hope this provides someone with a little help.

Answer (score 1):

Also, check if your repositories are not conflicting. 
If apt is producing errors, then fix those, and then issues with livepatch should be resolved as well.